# Find missing hours from one column and save as txt file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

Given a dataset as follows:

|  | date | NO2 | SO2 | O3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018/11/14 10:00 | 9 | 25 | 80 |
| 1 | 2018/11/14 12:00 | 9 | 26 | 88 |
| 2 | 2018/11/14 13:00 | 8 | 26 | 88 |
| 3 | 2018/11/14 14:00 | 8 | 34 | 88 |
| 4 | 2018/11/14 15:00 | 8 | 37 | 89 |
| 5 | 2018/11/14 17:00 | 8 | 72 | 40 |
| 6 | 2018/11/14 18:00 | 8 | 56 | 50 |
| 7 | 2018/11/14 19:00 | 7 | 81 | 22 |

I would like to find missing hours from `date` column, and save these missing date as `missing_date.txt`.

My code:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date']))
df = df.sort_index()
df = df.drop(columns=['date'])
df = df.resample('H').first().fillna(np.nan)
missing = df[df['NO2'].isnull()]
np.savetxt('./missing_date.txt', missing.index.to_series(), fmt='%s')
```

Out:

```
2018-11-14T11:00:00.000000000
2018-11-14T16:00:00.000000000
```

The problem:

1. not concise, maybe need to improve;
2. date format is not expected as follows: `2018/11/14 11:00`, `2018/11/14 16:00`.

How could I improve the code above? Thanks.

Comment: Are `date` unique?

Comment: Yes, they are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) working with unique datetimes:

```
#create sorted DatetimeIndex
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date').sort_index()

#if possible duplicates
#df = df.resample('H').first()

#if not duplicates
df = df.asfreq('H')

missing = df[df['NO2'].isna()]
```

For write to file is possible convert values of `DatetimeIndex` for custom format first by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) and then write by numpy or pandas:

```
s = missing.index.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M').to_series()

np.savetxt('./missing_date.txt', s, fmt='%s')
```

---

```
s.to_csv('./missing_date.txt', index=False)
```